# Connecting to my laptops localhost from my USB connected android device

Tags: c#, android, usb, localhost, asp.net-mvc-5

I have coded a C# MVC Internet Application with Visual Studio 2013 Express for Web on my laptop. I can compile and connect to this application with the following web address in my laptops browser: localhost:22101/

I am wishing to connect to this address in an Android application that I have coded, but am having some trouble connecting to the localhost on my laptop. My laptop is connected with a USB cable.

I have tried the following:

1. Tried to connect to my laptops IPv4 address from ipconfig
   (10.1.1.3)... no connection found.
2. Tried to connect to 10.0.2.2... no connection found

My laptop and cell phone are both connected to the same wireless router.

Is this possible? Can I please have some help with this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The local development server doesn't respond to external requests.

You will need to run it on a full blown iis I'm afraid.